# In Need of Recommendations for More Efficient Way to Write Conditional Branching Logic Involving Checkbox Fields

Tags: redcap

I know that conditional logic involving checkbox fields is different than that of multiple choice radio button (single answer) fields as each choice in checkbox fields is a separate variable. I am trying to write conditional branching logic for another field (a text box field) that will only appear if none of the choices in the checkox field are selected. The issue is that the checkbox field has numerous choices (~30-40 choices). Is there a concise way to write the conditional branching logic for the text box field such that it only appears if none of the checkbox fields are selected, without having to refer to all of the choice variables within the checkbox field?

EDIT: I found the answer for myself which is as follows:

There unfortunately isn't a concise way to write conditional branching logic when referring to all choices in a checkbox field. You would have to involve all choices in the conditional logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a response to this inquiry, there unfortunately isn't a concise way to write conditional branching logic when referring to all choices in a checkbox field. You would have to involve all choices in the conditional logic.